# Beego - Creating Model Form and ORM

Tags: model-view-controller, go, beego

I have created a model using the following code:

```
type UserProfile struct {
    Id                  int             `orm:"auto"`
    Name                string          `orm:"size(100)"`
    Email               string          `orm:"size(100)"`
    Type                string          `orm:"size(30)"`
    Admin               bool
    Car                 []*Car          `orm:"reverse(many)"`
}
```

Is there any way I can render a form directly using this structure? I think `valid:required` rakes care of validation, but how do we control form rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In controller：

```
func (this *AddController) Get() {
   this.Data["Form"] = & UserProfile{}
   this.TplNames = "index.tpl"
```

}

In template :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{.Form | renderform}}
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use bootstrap css with the forms ? Otherwise the generated form is very basic html, thank you.